# Swagger 2.0 anyOf replacement

Tags: json, schema, swagger, jsonschema

I have a definition model, lets name it `A`.

`A` has a property which is a complex object which could be of several types of complex objects.
How can I achieve it using swagger 2.0? `anyOf` is not supported on swagger, and I've checked into `discriminator` and polymorphic types here:

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/403

yet I don't see how I could use it for my need.
I've already built a polymorphic type (illustration):

```
  Father:
      discriminator: fatherType
  SonA:
    type: object
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/Father'
      - properties:
          fatherType:
            type: string
            enum:
              - SonA
          name:
            type: string
```

Using it inside my model `A` is not working as expected:

```
A
  type: object
  properties:
    father:
      $ref: '#/definitions/Father'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you've to wait for OpenAPI/Swagger spec 3.0 release, which supports `anyOf`.

You can find more information about OpenAPI/Swagger spec 3.0 from this [interview](https://www.infoq.com/articles/open-api-initiative-update) with Tony Tam.

Comment: I know it's coming in 3.0, but until then what is my best option for such a requirement where I need an object to be either A, B, or C? Should I just leave it as an empty object? So for my example A with be only this: `A type: object`

Comment: What about using [vendor extensions](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#vendorExtensions) for the time being, e.g. x-anyOf ?

Comment: I wouldn't want to use it, it'll be to restrictive and specific for the set of tools I will use. Guess I will have to wait then